# Cursor always returns 0 from SQL Queries

Tags: android, sqlite

Ive been trying to return values from a SQL query but it always has the value 0, not null. I've tried to find answers on both Google and SO, but I've found nothing.

Also, the database is working, as it can fill a ListView with data from the database itself.

Heres my code:

**BeaverDetailsDB**

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
        MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NIGHTS_AWAY };
private String[] NightsAway = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NIGHTS_AWAY };

public BeaverDetailsDB(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}




public DetailsSQLClass createName(String Name) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, Name);
    long insertId = db.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    Cursor cursor = db.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, allColumns,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null, null,
            null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    DetailsSQLClass newName = cursorToName(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newName;
}

public void createNightsAway(Integer TotalNightsAway) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NIGHTS_AWAY, TotalNightsAway);
    db.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    return;
}





public List<DetailsSQLClass> getAllNames() {
    List<DetailsSQLClass> Names = new ArrayList<DetailsSQLClass>();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        DetailsSQLClass Name = cursorToName(cursor);
        Names.add(Name);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return Names;
}



public Integer getNightsAway(String Name) {
    dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    int value = 9999;
    Cursor c = db.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, NightsAway,
    "Name" + " =  ?" ,new String[] {Name} , null, null, null, null);
    int x = c.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NIGHTS_AWAY);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        value = c.getInt(x); 
        int b = c.getCount();
    } else if (c.isNull(0)) {
        value = 55675; // Check if Column 0 is empty/null
    }
    c.close();
    dbHelper.close();
    return value;
}

public String DbQuery(String Name) {
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, "Name" + "='"
            + Name + "'", null, null, null, null);
    String result;
    c.moveToFirst();
    result = c.getString(0);
    c.close();
    dbHelper.close();
    return result;
}

private DetailsSQLClass cursorToName(Cursor cursor) {
    DetailsSQLClass Name = new DetailsSQLClass();
    Name.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    Name.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    return Name;
}
```

}

**MySQLiteHelper**

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "sqlBeaverDetails";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String COLUMN_NIGHTS_AWAY = "NightsAway";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sqlBeaverDetails.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = ("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + 
            " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " STRING, " + 
            COLUMN_NIGHTS_AWAY + " INTEGER );");

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

**AddBeaverDetailsActivity**

```
public class AddBeaverDetailsActivity extends Activity {

EditText etName;
EditText etNightsAway;

private BeaverDetailsDB datasource;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_beaver_details);


     datasource = new BeaverDetailsDB(this); datasource.open(); 
     etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBeaverName);
     etNightsAway = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNightsAway);}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void bSQLEnter(View v) { 
    String Name;
    String NightsAway;

    Name = etName.getText().toString();
    NightsAway = etNightsAway.getText().toString();
    int TotalNightsAway = Integer.parseInt(NightsAway);

    datasource.createName(Name);
    datasource.createNightsAway(TotalNightsAway);

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  ViewBeaverDetails.class);
    startActivity(i);

}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked me!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

**DetailsSQLClass**

```
public class DetailsSQLClass {
private long id;
private String Name;
private String NightsAway;

public long getId(){
    return id;
    }
public void setId(long id){
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName(){
    return Name;
    }
public void setName(String Name){
    this.Name = Name;
}

public String getNightsAway(){
    return NightsAway;
    }
public void setNightsAway(String NightsAway){
    this.NightsAway = NightsAway;
}

// Used for the ArrayAdapter
@Override
public String toString(){
    return Name;
}
```

}

**BeaverDetailsPage**

```
public class BeaverDetailsPage extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_beaver_details);

    String title = "";
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        title = extras.getString("BeaverName");}
    setTitle(title);

    BeaverDetailsDB db = new BeaverDetailsDB(getApplicationContext());

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBDetailsNightsAway);

    db.open();
    Integer value = db.getNightsAway(title);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    db.close();

}
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: are you always getting the message "Upgrading database from version..."?

Comment: in which function are you getting 0?

Comment: @petey Not that I know of, would it be shown in LogCat?

Comment: Yes it would show there, use the filter to help find it.

Comment: @RohanKandwal Sorry, I forgot to include the file! Its the TextView, on BeaverDetailsPage.

Comment: @petey I cant see anything about Upgrading the database there.

Comment: Ok, , you may run into issues later on with the onUpgrade method dropping your tables unexpectedly, maybe something like this : https://gist.github.com/petetandon/7949119

Comment: is `value = c.getInt(x);` returning something?

Comment: @RohanKandwal Yes, it has the value 0, which is different to the value I entered in on the entry form.

Comment: Then there lies your problem. Try using `while(c.moveToNext())` loop there and check if you get a value.

Comment: @RohanKandwal I know, I can't figure out why the cursor always returns 0

Comment: try replacing `x` with 0

Comment: @RohanKandwal It still returns 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                value = c.getInt(0);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
```

For others who have similar problems even after using code above,download `SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1` and then move out your application database using DDMS and see that you are having correct values in your database.

Comment: Im still getting a value of 0 unfortunately

Comment: Also if this still returns 0 please check what `c.getCount()` returns, if it too returns 0 then there is something wrong with query.

Comment: then it should have worked. What is actual value of `COLUMN_NIGHTS_AWAY` where name is whatever you passed?

Comment: How would I test that? I've tried using breakpoints, but they've never shown the SQL data values

Comment: Where are you actually testing the value of `value`? and  `value = 55675;` is wrong since max value of int can be 32568

Comment: download `SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1` and then move out your application database using `DDMS` and see it using the application i told you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as I had 2 insert statements, the NightsAway was being stored separately to the Name, so one record had a Name, and the other had the NightsAway! Thanks!

Comment: @BenS I am glad it helped you I am updating my answer to post your solution and some FYI, please upvote answers that helped you.. Happy Coding...!!!